# Why is cloudflare blocking my api request

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

I am trying to access the api https://api.btcxindia.com/order_book/ which is working fine in the browser however when I try to access it using file_get_contents or curl , i am getting Error 520, can someone tell why?

Tried

```
echo file_get_contents('https://api.btcxindia.com/order_book/');
```

And

```
curl 'https://api.btcxindia.com/order_book/' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: api.btcxindia.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0'
```

Both do not work.

Comment: I'm also getting a 520 error in the browser.

Comment: Yep, same here. *"Error 520 (...) Web server is returning an unknown error (...) Website is offline"*

Answer (score 0):

That is not CloudFlare blocking your request. Instead it is CloudFlare informing you that the API you are trying to access is offline. This could either be due to the owner's misconfiguration of DNS or their server/hosting being down.

If you own the website you may want to confirm your website is online or the DNS is configured correctly. If you do not own this website there is not much you can do but wait it out or contact the web administrator if you already know their contact details.

Edit: After discussing in the comments, it appears the website has a configuration error with a certain request type or certain clients. This is likely what is causing your error and is likely a web server error.

Regards

Comment: Since I can access the api in my browser, I assume the server is online, I think I am messing some header for cloudflare but not able to figure it out.

Comment: @ak111in What you are seeing when you visit it in your browser is a page by CloudFlare telling you that their main server is offline. Manually visiting it myself or using other status checker websites reveal that is is offline.

Comment: I am getting the expected data when I open the api link in browser and not the cloudflare error page. http://imgur.com/rfOi3Wy

Comment: @ak111in Interesting. Several other stack overflow users and external services report not being able to connect. There is your problem. Something is faulty in the web server configuration not allowing certain kinds of requests to continue. This is likely what is blocking your API request and what is causing other users and my connection issues. I suggest contacting whoever manages the API about this problem.

Comment: I have tried contacting them but they say that their is no issue on their end. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

New policies on Cloudflare: https://developers.cloudflare.com/api-shield/

## Availability

Cloudflare API Security products are available to Enterprise customers only, though anyone can set up Mutual TLS with a Cloudflare-managed certificate authority.